# Do all USB 3.0 micro cables use that weird double connector on the small end?

Tags: usb, usb-3

Example image:

[image]

There's really not much else to say but SU requires a minimum of characters.

Comment: Questions on SU should include some research you have already done, if you cannot find the answer using google or other resource then post your question with any research results you have found but did not answer your question, In other words we at SU expect you to try and answer your own question before you post it here.

Comment: @Moab did you think that maybe I thought this might be a question that other people might have? And that it would be valuable to have it answered here? No, apparently you just want to tell people to RTFM. Despite what you think, RTFM is not an appropriate answer on this site. I searched for the answer here and didn't see it, so I thought it appropriate to ask. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: I don't make the rules here, just inform those who don't know what they are. Hover you mouse over the upvote arrow on someone else's question. "This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear" you got the second half right. I haven't downvoted yet! The down arrow shows " This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: Then you should have just voted to close.

Comment: We are all here to learn. Stop being so negative, and read the rules, I did not make them by the way.

Comment: I'm not being negative - voting to close is a perfectly reasonable thing to do on SE sites. It seemed like a legit question. I thought that connector was proprietary for Samsung devices since I'd only ever seen it on newer Samsung phones. BTW the "Ask a question" page says nothing about expecting people to do basic research. Why would I hover over the downvote icon on my own question? You're expecting me to do weird things, based on the way the sites UI is set up.

Comment: You cannot read "Hover you mouse over the upvote arrow on someone else's question"

Comment: Was that a question? Why/how would I read the upvote text when I'm submitting a question?

Comment: So you can learn the Rules!

Comment: Ugh. You're not getting it. On the "Ask a question" page there is **nothing** about making sure you've done basic research about your question. So complaining to me about how I haven't done basic research is a bit absurd, since the site doesn't actually ask me to do that while I'm submitting a question.

Comment: No complaint, just Fact!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Do all USB 3.0 micro cables use that weird double connector on the small end?

Yes.

> USB 3.0 also introduced a new Micro-B cable plug, which consists of a
> standard USB 1.x/2.0 Micro-B cable plug, with additional 5-pin plug
> "stacked" on side of it.
>
> That way, USB 3.0 Micro-A host connector preserved its backward
> compatibility with the USB 1.x/2.0 Micro-B cable plugs.
>
> However, it is not possible to plug a USB 3.0 Micro-B plug into a USB
> 2.0 Micro-B receptacle, due to a physically larger connector.

...

> **Backward compatibility**
>
> USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 (or earlier) Type-A plugs and receptacles are
> designed to interoperate.
>
> USB 3.0 Type-B receptacles, such as those found on peripheral devices,
> are larger than in USB 2.0 (or earlier versions), and accept both the
> larger USB 3.0 Type-B plug and the smaller USB 2.0 (or earlier) Type-B
> plug. USB 3.0 Type B plugs are larger than USB 2.0 (or earlier) Type-B
> plugs; therefore, USB 3.0 Type-B plugs cannot be inserted into USB 2.0
> (or earlier) Type-B receptacles.

Source [USB 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Connectors)

Comment: I would add that as both connectors are backwards compatible, you can use USB 2.0 cables to connect USB 3.0 devices or any combination of USB 2.0/3.0 host/device.

Comment: @Marki555. It wasn't part of the question, but I will add it ;)

Comment: It was meant more as additional information to the OP and other readers, not you directly, but adding it to the answer is a good idea.